# How can I specify a default time for a ndb.TimeProperty()?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I find myself stuck on this problem, and repeated Googling, checking SO, and reading numerous docs has not helped me get the right answer, so I hope this isn't a bad question.

One entity I want to create is an event taking place during a convention.  I'm giving it the property `start_time = ndb.TimeProperty()`.  I also have a property `date = messages.DateProperty()`, and I'd like to keep the two discrete (in other words, not using `DateTimeProperty`).

When a user enters information to create an event, I want to specify defaults for any fields they do not enter at creation and I'd like to set the default time as midnight, but I can't seem to format it correctly so the service accepts it (constant **503 Service Unavailable** response when I try it using the API explorer).

Right now I've set things up like this (some unnecessary details removed):

```
event_defaults = {...
    ...
    "start_time": 0000,
    ...
    }
```

and then I try looping over my default values to enter them into a dictionary which I'll use to `.put()` the info on the server.

```
data = {field.name: getattr(request, field.name) for field in request.all_fields()

for default in event_defaults:
    if data[default] in (None, []):
        data[default] = event_defaults[default]
        setattr(request, default, event_defaults[default])
```

In the logs, I see the error **Encountered unexpected error from ProtoRPC method implementation: BadValueError (Expected time, got 0)**.  I have also tried using the `time` and `datetime` modules, but I must be using them incorrectly, because I still receive errors.

I suppose I could work around this problem by using `ndb.StringProperty()` instead, and just deal with strings, but then I'd feel like I would be missing out on a chance to learn more about how `GAE` and `NDB` work (all of this is for a project on udacity.com, so learning is certainly the point).

So, how can I structure my default time properly for midnight?  Sorry for the wall of text.

Link to code on [github](https://github.com/coralvanda/ud858/tree/master/Lesson_2/00_Conference_Central).  The `conference.py` file contains the code I'm having the trouble with, and `models.py` contains my definitions for the entities I'm working with.

Update: I'm a dummy.  I had my model class using a `TimeProperty()` and the corresponding message class using a `StringField()`, but I was never making the proper conversion between expected types.  That's why I could never seem to give it the right thing, but it expected two different things at different points in the code.  Issue resolved.

Comment: I attempted to use `"start_time": datetime.time.max` just to see if I could get another value to work, and received this error: `Encountered unexpected error from ProtoRPC method implementation: ValidationError (Expected type (<type 'int'>, <type 'long'>) for field start_time, found 23:59:59.999999 (type <type 'datetime.time'>))`

Comment: Also attempted to use `"start_time": (2300)` to see if that would work.  Received this error: `Encountered unexpected error from ProtoRPC method implementation: BadValueError (Expected time, got 2300)`

Comment: At this point, I'd be happy with any default time, as long as it works!  I can't figure out how to get it to accept anything, because it always seems to have an issue with my format.  I've been looking through other projects on github to see how people handle the `ndb.TimeProperty()`, but I haven't found anything so far.

Comment: which model should we be looking at in models.py?

Comment: It's the session entity, but I think I figured it out.  I'll edit my original question  to make it clear that I am no longer seeking an answer.

Answer (score 1):

TimeProperty expects a datetime.time value

```
import datetime

event_defaults = {...
    ...
    "start_time": datetime.time(),
    ...
    }
```

More in the docs: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entity-property-reference#Date_and_Time

Comment: Tried it as you suggested, but still received an error.  Logs show this: `Encountered unexpected error from ProtoRPC method implementation: ValidationError (Expected type (<type 'int'>, <type 'long'>) for field start_time, found 00:00:00 (type <type 'datetime.time'>))`

Comment: Are you using a plain ndb Timeproperty? B/c datetime.time satisfies the type being asked for. Or using  endpoints or a related framework, or a custom type?

Comment: Anyway the error suggests a start time of the form: `(<type 'int'>, <type 'long'>)`. So in the meantime you can try to edit to match that format?: `"start_time": (0,0),`

Comment: I am using endpoints.  I've edited my original question to include a link to the code, if that might be helpful.  My `class` definition uses `ndb.TimeProperty()` and inherits from another class which inherits from `ndb.Model`.  I tried using `"start_time": (0,0),`, and received this error message: `Encountered unexpected error from ProtoRPC method implementation: ValidationError (Expected type (<type 'int'>, <type 'long'>) for field start_time, found (0, 0) (type <type 'tuple'>))`

Answer (score 0):

Use the datetime() library to convert it into a valid ndb time property value

```
    if data['time']:
        data['time'] = datetime.strptime(data['time'][:10], "%H:%M").time()
    else:
        data['time'] = datetime.datetime.now().time()
```

ps: Don't forget to change data['**time**'] with your field name